# How to show an outside page into Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I am new to Salesforce and I am trying to show an outside page into Salesforce. 
I thought about making a lightning web component and using an iframe to include the page. Is this possible? Are there other best approaches to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be the way to go. I think Salesforce has sth. in their Community Area called "CMS Connect" which allows to display external Content from a CMS inside a Community but in general Iframes are the tool to display whole websites.

You should keep in mind though:

1. The page has to allow embedding by external Domains (meaning sending the respective CORS headers - which in returns means you should be the owner of the page if you would like to configure it)
2. If you are working in LEX / Community Context you may have to add the domain to the CSP Trusted Sites in order to display it (depending on your Org / Community Security Settings)
3. Lockerservice / LWC Compiler prohibits the usage of the allow attribute. This is at least required for Chrome in order to get access to additional Features like geolocation, Camera, Microphone. If your Site is intended to provide any functionality for it you will not be able to use it via iframe in lwcs (for chrome users)

There is also something called [Canvas App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm) (which is in the end also an iframe i think just with a couple of apis on top) which can be used to integrate third party applications - but they are only available in old aura components (no lwc equivalent available as of today) and is depending on your use case maybe also an overkill

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I will go with trying out the iframe.

Comment: how would I go about displaying external data into this iframe? Would an Aura Component be a better approach?

Comment: there is no difference between an aura component and a lwc - the iframe just displays whatever is hosted on the site you are embedding. So the whole logic, layout etc. has to implemented on the external Site / App - which means there is not really an answer to your question